# ERROR at line 1 : ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to merge rows from source table(${STAGEDB_UID}.${CLIENTNAME}_${DIMNAME}*RAW) to target table(${CLIENTNAME}*${DIMNAME}_STG) and i have also used distinct key work to avoid duplicates. But still merge is not happening and  script is failing with "ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables". Could you please help me on this ?

I have added DISTINCT Keyword to avoid this error. But this merge is not happening.

```
MERGE INTO ${CLIENTNAME}_${DIMNAME}_STG M
                USING (SELECT DISTINCT cn.CUST_ID ,
                    cn.CR_PERSON_ID ,
                    cn.AGE ,
                    cn.DOB ,
                    cn.GENDER ,
                    cn.POSTCODE ,
                    cn.PREMIUM_FLAG ,
                    cn.SPARKS_FLAG ,
                    cn.WCS_FLAG ,
                    'Identified Shoppers' AS CUST_IDENTIFICATION ,
                    CASE WHEN cn.AGE < 35 THEN 'UNDER 35' 
                         WHEN cn.AGE BETWEEN 35 AND 44 THEN '35-44' 
                         WHEN cn.AGE BETWEEN 45 AND 54 THEN '45-54' 
                         WHEN cn.AGE BETWEEN 55 AND 64 THEN '55-64' 
                         WHEN cn.AGE > 64 THEN '65+'  
                         ELSE 'Unassigned' END CUST_AGE_BAND,
                    CASE WHEN cn.GENDER = 'U' THEN 'Unassigned' 
                         WHEN cn.GENDER = 'F' THEN 'Female' 
                         WHEN cn.GENDER = 'M' THEN 'Male' 
                         ELSE 'Unassigned' END CUST_GENDER,
                    CASE WHEN cn.SPARKS_FLAG = 0 OR cn.SPARKS_FLAG = 1 THEN 'Sparks Customers'
                         WHEN cn.SPARKS_FLAG = 2 THEN 'Non Sparks Customers' 
                         ELSE 'Non Sparks Customers' END SPARKS_MEMBER ,
                    CASE WHEN cn.SPARKS_FLAG = 0 THEN 'Unregistered Customers'
                         WHEN cn.SPARKS_FLAG = 1 THEN 'Registered Customers'
                         WHEN cn.SPARKS_FLAG = 2 THEN 'Left Scheme'
                         ELSE 'Non Sparks Customers' END SPARKS_MEMBER_TYPE,
                         cn.EXPERIAN_AGE,
                         cn.EXPERIAN_AFFLUENCE,
                         cn.EXPERIAN_LIFESTAGE,
                         cn.EXPERIAN_HH_COMPOSITION
                    FROM ${STAGEDB_UID}.${CLIENTNAME}_${DIMNAME}_RAW cn
                    inner join ${OPSKEYGEN_UID}.DIM_KEY_MSTR t
                    on cn.cust_id = t.reference_key where KEY_IDENTIFIER = 147
                            UNION ALL
                    select distinct 
                    '-'||STORE_ID ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    'Non-Identified Shoppers' ,
                    'Non-Identified Shoppers' ,
                    'Non-Identified Shoppers' ,
                    'Non-Identified Shoppers' ,
                    'Non-Identified Shoppers' ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null from ${STAGEDB_UID}.${CLIENTNAME}_VN_RAW
                    where store_id is not null) S
        on (M.CUST_ID = S.CUST_ID) 
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET M.CR_PERSON_ID=S.CR_PERSON_ID ,M.AGE=S.AGE ,M.DOB=S.DOB ,M.GENDER=S.GENDER ,M.POSTCODE=S.POSTCODE ,M.PREMIUM_FLAG=S.PREMIUM_FLAG ,M.SPARKS_FLAG=S.SPARKS_FLAG,
        M.WCS_FLAG=S.WCS_FLAG ,M.CUST_IDENTIFICATION=S.CUST_IDENTIFICATION ,M.CUST_AGE_BAND=S.CUST_AGE_BAND,M.CUST_GENDER=S.CUST_GENDER,M.SPARKS_MEMBER=S.SPARKS_MEMBER ,M.SPARKS_MEMBER_TYPE=S.SPARKS_MEMBER_TYPE,M.EXPERIAN_AGE=S.EXPERIAN_AGE ,M.EXPERIAN_AFFLUENCE=S.EXPERIAN_AFFLUENCE ,M.EXPERIAN_LIFESTAGE=S.EXPERIAN_LIFESTAGE ,M.EXPERIAN_HH_COMPOSITION=S.EXPERIAN_HH_COMPOSITION
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (CUST_ID,CR_PERSON_ID,AGE,DOB ,GENDER ,POSTCODE ,PREMIUM_FLAG ,SPARKS_FLAG ,WCS_FLAG ,CUST_IDENTIFICATION ,CUST_AGE_BAND,CUST_GENDER, SPARKS_MEMBER ,SPARKS_MEMBER_TYPE,EXPERIAN_AGE,EXPERIAN_AFFLUENCE,EXPERIAN_LIFESTAGE,EXPERIAN_HH_COMPOSITION)
        VALUES(S.CUST_ID,S.CR_PERSON_ID,S.AGE,S.DOB ,S.GENDER ,S.POSTCODE ,S.PREMIUM_FLAG ,S.SPARKS_FLAG ,S.WCS_FLAG ,S.CUST_IDENTIFICATION ,S.CUST_AGE_BAND,S.CUST_GENDER, S.SPARKS_MEMBER ,S.SPARKS_MEMBER_TYPE,s.EXPERIAN_AGE,s.EXPERIAN_AFFLUENCE,s.EXPERIAN_LIFESTAGE,s.EXPERIAN_HH_COMPOSITION)
        ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use union as you have got a lot of manipulations involved hence union will do your distinct work at first also you have used distinct seperately in two seperate queries thatll still o/p duplicates causing that error

```
  Using(Select distinct * from (select.... 
    Union all 
    Select * from...)) 

   Or simply union
```